# Django Pagination always raising PageNotAnInteger

Tags: python, django, pagination

I have this strange issue where regardless of what I pass to my view, Django's Pagination is always saying that my page number is not an integer.

```
training_sesions = TrainingSession.objects.all()
page_num = int(request.GET.get('page', 1))
paginator = Paginator(training_sessions, 25)
page = paginator.page(page_num)

try:
    sessions = paginator.page(page)
except (PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage):
    sessions = paginator.page(1)
```

I have validated that page_num is an int, paginator and page get set to the appropriate classes, and my request parameter is being passed correctly.

I have even tried passing just a straight number to paginator.page and I still get the exception.

Comment: could you post exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the OP comments, I was redundantly passing the page object from the paginator to another call to paginator.page.
Changed to the number and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Before the `try/except` in your code you try setting the paginator's page and its this line that is raising the error, since you are setting the page to something else inside the block you can just delete this line and adjust the index variable you are using to look up the page.

```
training_sesions = TrainingSession.objects.all()
page_num = int(request.GET.get('page', 1))
paginator = Paginator(training_sessions, 25)

try:
    sessions = paginator.page(page_num)
except (PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage):
    sessions = paginator.page(1)
```